# Keyboard overlaping issue with web view developed in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

Keyboard is overlapping text editor area

We have created a xamarin app and in a webview we are loading the application.

when we type text in text editor its not being scroll up, text goes behind the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Do you have nested scrollviews，and is it full screen ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to not hide an entry below the keyboard, the simplest solution I found is to use the scrollview as in the example:

```
<ContentView>
    <ScrollView Margin="0, 5">
        <StackLayout Margin="40, 5" Spacing="10">
            <Entry Text="{Binding TextEntry1}" Placeholder="Text entry 1"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding TextEntry2}" Placeholder="Text entry 2"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding TextEntry3}" Placeholder="Text entry 3"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: We have tried this as well, but the scroll stopped within web-view, any other option?

Comment: With a FlexLayout in place of ScrollView?                                   
`<ContentView>
    <FlexLayout Direction="Column" JustifyContent="Center">
        <StackLayout Margin="40, 5" Spacing="10">
            <Entry Text="{Binding TextEntry1}" Placeholder="Text entry 1"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding TextEntry2}" Placeholder="Text entry 2"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding TextEntry3}" Placeholder="Text entry 3"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </FlexLayout >
</ContentView>`

Comment: For now, I have managed it with scroll-view, it's working almost all devices we have, but not for 1 device, I will try FlexLayout with the next milestone of the app. Anyway thanks.